# Shortening media queries in Sass

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

In Sass, I've had to chain together three separate media queries to handle the responsiveness. It currently is a long mess looking like this:

```
@media (max-width: $tablet-portrait-width) and
       (max-height: $tablet-portrait-height) and
       (min-height: $landscape-min-height)
```

I want to shorten the queries, but am unsure how. Is it possible to make this easier to read?

The variables used are defined in a settings page I've made and have these values:

```
$landscape-min-height: 200px;
$tablet-portrait-height: 1024px;
$tablet-portrait-width: 768px;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `@mixin` (this is similar to a function) and define its parameters, then call it where you want with `@include`. You can copy the code below to [SassMeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/) to see the results.

```
@mixin mediaQ($max-width: 0, $max-height: 0, $min-height: 0) {
  @media screen and (max-width: $max-width)
                and (max-height: $max-height)
                and (min-height: $min-height) {
    body {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  }
}

$landscape-min-height: 200px;
$tablet-portrait-height: 1024px;
$tablet-portrait-width: 768px;

@include mediaQ(
  $tablet-portrait-width,
  $tablet-portrait-height,
  $landscape-min-height
);
```